# What kind of window/glass is this?

Tags: insulation, windows

I'm wondering what kind of glass this window is made of. 
Is this a "strong" window like laminate? 
Finally, is it safe to apply a film such as tint or "security film"?

[image: Window Edge]

[image: Window Markings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular glass
Not laminate or tempered
Yes, you can apply films to it

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how you determined that (visually or by the label inscribed in the corner?)

Comment: Tempered normally says that in the text on it.

Comment: As Ecnerwal noted, if it's tempered, it says so. This doesn't say so. That it's a window in the corner of the wall and off the floor indicate that tempered glass isn't necessary in this area. The only reason it would be required is if there were a door located on the side of the window that we can not see